# Discord.js First Time Message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, messaging

I want my bot to say some messages when it first joined the server, is there any way to do that?(Like calling a function when first joined)I tried the welcome messages but they worked only when people joined.

Answer (score 1):

[`guildCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate) fires whenever the client joins a guild:

```js
client.on('guildCreate', (guild) => {
  // send a message to the guild owner
  guild.owner.send('Thanks for adding me to your server');

  // OR send a message to the systemChannel
  guild.systemChannel.send('Thanks for adding me to your server');

  // OR find a channel, like "General" for example
  let channel = guild.channels.cache.find(
    (ch) => ch.name.toLowerCase() === 'general',
  );

  if (!channel) return console.log('Where should I post?');

  channel.send('Hey everyone');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to know if your bot has been added to a server or not.

```js
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    let log = client.channels.get("channel id");
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor("I have been added to the server")
        .setThumbnail(
            guild.iconURL ||
            "icon url"
        )
        .setColor("GREEN")
        .addField("» Server Name:", `**${guild.name}**`)
        .addField("» Server ID:", `\`\`\`${guild.id}\`\`\``)
        .addField(
            "Server Information:",
            `**Server Ownwe: \`${guild.owner}\`\nServer Region: \`${guild.region}\`\nMember Count: \`${guild.members.size}\`\nChannel Count: \`${guild.channels.size}\`**`
        )
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(client.user.username, client.user.avatarURL);
    log.send(embed);
});
client.on("guildDelete", guild => {
    let log = client.channels.get("channel id");
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor("I was kicked from the server")
        .setThumbnail(
            guild.iconURL ||
            "icon url"
        )
        .setColor("RED")
        .addField("» Server Name:", `**${guild.name}**`)
        .addField("» Server ID:", `\`\`\`${guild.id}\`\`\``)
        .addField(
            "Server Information:",
            `**Server Owner: \`${guild.owner}\`\nServer Region: \`${guild.region}\`\nMember Count: \`${guild.members.size}\`\nChannel Count: \`${guild.channels.size}\`**`
        )
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(client.user.username, client.user.avatarURL);
    log.send(embed);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must be using the [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) event which fires when a user joins a server the bot is in. Use the [`guildCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate) event instead.

```js
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
await guild.channels.fetch();
await guild.owner.fetch();
let channel = guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")).find(c => c.name.startsWith('general')) || guild.channels.cache.first();
if(!channel) return guild.owner.send('...');
channel.send('...')

})
```

Answer (score 0):

When a user joins a server you can save that in a local database on your sever. So the first time they join you wont find them in your database and you can send the message, if they leave and rejoin you can find them in your database so you dont send your message.